# How to hide an email address?

Tags: javascript

To mention I'm a beginner to Javascript though I have some prior experience with Java

Write a function to hide an email address. Display the first and last letter and substitute with a dot the other letters.

```
function protect(mail) {

...........

}

console.log(protect("test@ing.pub.ro"));

console.log(protect("danalex@ing.pub.ro"));

console.log(protect("mailupb2018@fing.pub.ro"));
```

Output:

t..t@ing.pub.ro

d.....x@ing.pub.ro

m.........8@fing.pub.ro

I thought this would work but it doesen't:

```
function protect(mail){
let b = mail.indexOf("@");
    for(let i=1; i<b-1; i++){
       mail.replace(".",mail.charAt(i));
    }
    return mail;
}
```

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific roadblock you're running into in a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `split` and `repeat` with template literals:

```js
function protect(mail) {
  var [name, domain] = mail.split("@");
  var blockedName = `${name[0]}${".".repeat(name.length - 2)}${name[name.length - 1]}`;
  return `${blockedName}@${domain}`;
}

console.log(protect("test@ing.pub.ro"));

console.log(protect("danalex@ing.pub.ro"));

console.log(protect("mailupb2018@fing.pub.ro"));
```